# Python requests MaxRetryError Raise connection error adapters.py (HOW to trap BAD connections?)

Tags: python, connection, python-requests

I'm writing a script that tries to log in useing basic auth and requests. It generlly works, but I need to trap the ip's that are down at the moment. When I try to connect to a broken link like this:

```
While ..... :
       For .. in ..
          .....
          with r = requests.get('http://' + ip , auth=(username, password))
          ...
       Except e
```

It raises an error like this.

File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 378, in send
  raise ConnectionError(e)

Can you help me?
Post post post :D

Comment: Could you show a representative sample of what code you have actually written?

Comment: And ideally the entire traceback as well.

Comment: The code isn't on this computer. I will upload it tonightI just need the except to skip this IP and go to the next of the for in loop I think.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with an

```
except:
                print("Oops!  Something went wrong, the ip is probably unreachable. Try agai")
                pass
```